# Netflix API simple query for queue

Tags: netflix

I am playing with the Netflix API. I am confused on what they want as the 'UserID'. (for a protected query)
I am sending in this string (after authentication) to get the User's queue: 
http://api-public.netflix.com/users/'userID'/queues

This is return from authentication (not the real token) but what part of it is the userID?

```
oauth_token=xxx4ewzxxx8xx3xxxx3x9hv&oauth_token_secret=xxx8xxxx7xxd&
application_name=MyFlix&login_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-
user.netflix.com%2Foauth%2Flogin%3Foauth_token%3Dxxx4ewzxxx8xx3xxxx3x9hv
```

Maybe I am not even approaching it from the right angle. Any documentation or code I have found glosses over that part (My netflix ID doesn't work and I assume it should be part of the oauth token I get back, not my normal netflix ID)

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit old question, but you need to get access token which will give you userid.
You can get access token when user agrees that your application can access his netflix account by calling API

```
 http://api-public.netflix.com/oauth/access_token
```

These information you will later use for communcation with api.

Hope it helps.

Find more here: http://developer.netflix.com/docs/read/Security part Send Us the Subscriber’s Authorized Request Token

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for the User ID, which I believe will be in a different transaction anyway. But I found out recently that Netflix has stopped its developer program (no new developers), so it has become a mute point for me.

Comment: Hi Yosem. Correct way to get userId is from AccessToken. You need user to link his account with your application. Then you ask for AccessToken (It can be done only once, you have to use same RequestToken) and you will receive user_id, oauth_token and oauth_token_secret. You're right, they dont issue any new developer keys. But existing ones are working fine.